# How can i get reward to my Customers/Users through UBER deep link?

Tags: ios, uber-api

I am using [UBER deep link](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk) in my iOS app.
I have configured Client-ID, Server-token & also deepLink . Yes through my app user can book UBER. but problem is how can i reward to my customer ?. How can i get to know that my user has booked UBER through my application ?

**Note**: My users are Indian.

Your one line knowledge/answer/idea can help me.

Comment: What does "but problem is how can i reward to my customer ?" mean?

Comment: @KyleDavis when user book  uber from my app. i just need to be notified. thats it. so that further i can reward him (buy some coffee). Is there any webcall from UBER end ?

Comment: Gotcha, if you deeplink into the app, you would not be able to have confirmation on whether the user actually took a ride or not. You would have to build the request flow into your app directly for that information (that is possible through the privileged 'request' scope - you can read about it on the developer docs).